# Axon ReplayingCluster with JTA transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, jta, axon

For my Java EE (7) project I want to use the Axon framework. 
One of the parameters of the Axon `ReplayingCluster` is a `TransactionManager`, but Axon only supports `NoTransactionManager` and `SpringTransactionManager`.

But if i'm not mistaken with JTA, transactions are already managed by the application server in the `EntityManager` (which I have stored in the `JpaEventStore`).

My question: when I use `ReplayingCluster` with `NoTransactionManager`, does this mean JTA will still provide transactions functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event replays may involve thousands if not millions of events. Therefore it is often not feasible to manage a single replay in a single transaction (assuming your event listeners make changes that require transactions at all).

Axon uses a `TransactionManager` during replays to commit changes each time a batch of events is replayed. The size of this batch is configurable using the `commitThreshold` parameter.

Now, I don't have experience using JTA but my understanding is that a transaction is automatically created when a bean method is invoked and committed when that method returns. Meaning that when you trigger a replay it will do so in a single transaction.

My advice therefore is to supply your own implementation to the `ReplayingCluster`. On a EJB server this implementation may look something like this:

```
class JtaTransactionManager implements TransactionManager<UserTransaction> {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public UserTransaction startTransaction() {
        UserTransaction utx = ctx.getUserTransaction();
        utx.begin();
        return utx;
    }

    @Override
    public void commitTransaction(UserTransaction utx) {
        utx.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void rollbackTransaction(UserTransaction utx) {
        utx.rollback();
    }

}
```

You can then annotate the bean that initiates the replay with `@TransactionManagement(BEAN)` to notify the application that you will manage these transactions yourself (this will not affect transaction management elsewhere).